# How do I count the files in the current directory whose names are at least 5 characters long?

Tags: files, grep, ls

I am trying to use `ls` and `grep`. However, I cannot figure out a way to count how many files in the current directory have a name long at least 5 characters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: should files in subfolders be considered?

Comment: No just the current directory, not recursive

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How would you grep for lines with at least five characters?

Comment: and directory names should be skipped, only files?

Comment: It's a question I've been given, it is "Count how many files in the current directory have names containing at least 5 characters.", I interpreted it as just files not directories.

Comment: @2310, note, this filename `a.txt` has also 5 charatcers, including extension. You see how many questions were asked?  Advice: always describe and elaborate your questions with details!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this @RomanPerekhrest, I however have no clue how to count character instead of just checking them against a given string.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please click the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simple **`find`** + **`wc`** commands solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "?????*" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework, the assignment may be looking for something like:

```
ls | grep ..... | wc -l
```

Though I would do:

```
set -- ?????*
echo $#
```

or

```
files=(?????*)
echo ${#files[@]}
```

Here the important work is done by the shell glob `.` which says to match one character of a filename; by including 5 of them followed by a * (any number of characters), we generate the list of files with at least 5 characters in them.

The counting is then done by the `$#` shell parameter in the `set` solution, or by counting the elements in the array.